# Как мне на языке LO basic, найти строки с определенным текстом и вывести их на другой лист

Tags: libre-office, libre-office-calc

Есть таблица `LO calc` допустим из двух столбцов:

```
номер и имя 
1       Яблоко
2       Ананас
3       Яблоко
4       Апельсин
5       Банан
```

Необходимо написать макрос, который будет искать во втором столбце значение **`«Яблоко»`** и образовывать на другом листе новую таблицу состоящую из строк со значением **`«Яблоко»`**. 
Макрос необходимо написать именно под `LO calc`, на языке `LO basic`, не путать с *VBA*.